# Modifying a compiled .EXE file's "File Version", and "Product Version" attributes

Tags: c#, file, msbuild, versioning

I am looking to add `Software Version` and `Release Number` into the `.EXE` files of the different pieces of software that I develop. I would like to store them in `File Version` and `Product Version` attributes respectively.

Additionally, I would like to do this after compilation. I am writing a C# program that will be executed after Bamboo successfully builds and deploys the software to it's staged location.

Is it possible to modify `File Version` and `Product Version` file attributes of a compiled `.EXE` file with C#?

If so, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @OlivierRogier dead link?

Comment: @ReRoute - It's 2 links. They both work.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Ahh, thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/debug/pe-format & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Comment: I am having a difficult time extracting useful information from either of those links. Maybe I am missing something.